# CSS not() doesn't work as expected

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand why the following doesn't work. As far as I understand it shouldn't give me a box shadow if the `form__group` element is a child of `.modal` yet it does.

```
div:not(.modal) .form__group:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0 0 #ccc;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJmddj

Comment: There is another div that match the query though and they are inside the one with modal class, so it's targeting that `modal__body`.

Comment: `div:not(.modal)` *does* include `<div class="modal__body">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__body">
    <div class="form__group">
      Hover on me for the box shadow - it shouldn't be there
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you remove the modal div, you get:

```
  <div class="modal__body"> <!-- fits the "div:not(.modal)" -->
    <div class="form__group">
      Hover on me for the box shadow - it shouldn't be there
    </div>
  </div>
```

Since `.modal__body` is not `.modal` does it fit your statement.

Solution is to add `.modal__body` to the selector:

```
div:not(.modal) .modal__body .form__group:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0 0 #ccc;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wadvKZ

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `modal__body` / have to use not for `modal` like this: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/QbvWGW)**

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">  
    <div class="form__group">
      Hover on me for the box shadow - it shouldn't be there
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="modal__body">
    <div class="form__group">
      Hover on me for the box shadow - it shouldn't be there
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal:not>.form__group:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 0 0 red;
} 
.modal__body>.form__group:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 0 0 #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Selector form__group is never used This inspection detects unused CSS classes or IDs within a file. "